# Special case of Cannizaro reaction of formaldehyde with 100% NaOH/KOH follows 4th order kinetics

Tags: organic-chemistry, reaction-mechanism, kinetics

It is given that when we use $50{-}\pu{60\%}\ \ce{KOH}$ in a Cannizaro reaction of formaldehyde, the reaction follows third order kinetics, but under special cases of Cannizaro reactions it was given than when formaldehyde reacts with $\pu{100\%}\ \ce{NaOH/KOH}$ the reaction follows fourth order kinetics.

What is the reason for this change in the order of reaction with an increase in the concentration of base?

Comment: Doesn't https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Cannizzaro_reaction answer this?